# Google play sign key

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, google-play-console

My client has given me an android project to fix some errors and add new features. This app was created and published on google play console by another programmer who currently has gone. So, now comes time to upgrade to the new version, but I don't have the original signing key. So my client said me to create a new app in google play console and put the new upgraded version. But when I tried to upload signed bundle with new keystore I got this error
[image]

my build gradle picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DITcg.png)

What can I do in order to solve this problem?

Upd: Same error when I upload release version. Also when I upload bundles of other projects to the app, no error occur.

Upd2: If my client request for 'Upgrade your app signing key for new installs'. Will it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here I write how I solve this problem.

1. Change application id in module build gradle file
2. delete testCoverageEnabled in module build gralde

b

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        testCoverageEnabled true
    }
}
```

3. Clean project
4. change version code

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload the `app-release.aab` not that `app-debug.aab`. It should be in the `app/release` folder while the debug one should be in the `app/build/outputs/apk/debug`.

Comment: Unfortunately, got same error. It's seems app key are linked to the android studio project. Can I remove all links to the google play console app in android studio project? Also added my build gradle.

Comment: When I upload another android projects to the google play console, no errors occur.

Comment: @AkylbekSultanov77 Did you change the `applicationId` in the gradle? If it is the same as the old one, it can't be uploaded.

Comment: I tried this, but not helped

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you're getting an error that the AAB isn't signed, then you're not signing it. If you use the wrong key, you get an error saying the upload key doesn't match. [Here's the instructions on how to sign your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign_release)

If you don't have the original app signing key, you can't update the app anymore. You'll have to create a new one, which is basically a completely new app with no connection to the original. And I'm not sure if having two apps with the same `applicationId` (i.e. `kg.ilimbox.mobile`) on the same developer account would be a problem, it's meant to be unique.

---

But you *might* be ok if your app is enrolled in [Play App Signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#app-signing-google-play) though - basically how that works is the Play Store holds your app-signing key, and it uses that to sign APKs created from the AAB bundles (the bundles allow it to create custom APKs for a specific device, and those need to be signed with the app key, so the Play Store needs to have that).

In this case, when you upload an AAB, you're signing it with an "upload key", which is basically how the Play Store checks it's an authorised upload. And you can ask them to reset that certificate, so you can use a different key. They push this as a feature, so that if you lose your key, you don't lose the ability to update the app (because Google holds the actual app signing key)

There's a link to the key change request process in that last link - you basically have to contact them while logged into the developer account (so they can see your email matches the one associated with the account), you create a new upload key and give them the certificate, and they'll update your app entry so you use that new one to sign AABs. You won't be able to upload for a few days though. You can see the current app signing and upload certificate hashes under **App integrity**, so you'll be able to see when they update

---

You *can* request an app signing key upgrade (one time only) but ideally you won't need that, it's better to update the upload key if you have the option

Comment: Yea, thank's for your answer. I think it will be usefull for those who will read this post. I'm already solve this problem